# The real line has cardinality at most $\aleph_2$, but transfinite ordinal space has arbitrarily high cardinality: what is wrong?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces, cardinals, ordinals

In the context of supertasks, people and mathematicians are comfortable with the idea of transfinite ordinal time, that is, that time can be divided into an arbitrarily high number of steps. In most cases the number of steps is limited to be $\omega$, but some models, such as Hamkins infinite time Turing machines, assume that a finite amount of time  can be divided into a number of steps of arbitrarily high cardinality. I think we can safely extend the concept from time to space (actually the question is the same, just that I think many people will find it easier to identify space with the real line).  Then, the original question: The real line has $2^{\aleph_0}$ (which I guess is at most  $\aleph_2$) points. But if we can partition it into a number of intervals of arbitrarily high cardinality, shouldn't the number (or set) of points on it have at least the same cardinality? (or you can have more intervals than points?). I am obviously confused. Please help!!

Comment: I don't get why there are three votes to close. This is a legitimate question...

Comment: Why the close votes to this question?  I believe that at its heart this question is requesting clarification on the nature of Hamkins's Infinite Time Turing Machine model and how it relates to other mathematical concepts.  IMHO such issues clearly fall under the scope of math.SE.  (I'm just a bit later than @Asaf.)

Comment: three vote to close??

Comment: I am tempted to vote to close just to see who initiated this closure. :-)

Comment: but cant you vote for not to close?

Comment: This is not how the system works, but if some time passes by (and if enough people on the reviewing system vote to leave open) then the closing votes decay and dissipate. I voted to leave open, and I saw that a few others have as well. But still... I'm curious, because I see a closing vote as "not a real question" on many set theory related questions. I wonder if the culprit is the same person, and why would they do that...

Comment: thanks. I dont know, they might be tired of my questions. I ask to many, and although I try to think they well, I find it very difficult to get right a good sense of many concepts that escape me because I dont have a formal education in the subject (plus I am not as smart as most of the members here). Some people get angry or tired, but they would need to calm down a little and understand that this is not MathOverflow, this site is to help confused people!

Comment: I would say this question is in the top 10% we see in terms of thought going into it.  I don't understand a vote to close.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hamkins's construction doesn't really assume "assume that a finite amount of time can be divided into a number of steps of arbitrarily high cardinality". Is merely proposes using an arbitrary *ordinal* (of whatever cardinality) as the time coordinate for the Turing machine computation, and investigates the consequences of such a decision. It doesn't depend on the full ordinal indexed time axis to correspond to "a finite amount of time", or to a subset of $\mathbb R$.

Indeed, Theorem 1.1 of the article you link to says that even if we *don't* assume a particular cardinality of the time axis, it is impossible for the machine to *halt* after more than countable steps. So essentially, the possibility of an uncountably long computation is allowed by the definition only to permit an argument that it is not an interesting case; all we really need to consider is computations that terminate in less than $\omega_1$ time.

Now it is well known that every ordinal *below* $\omega_1$ can be embedded not only into the real interval $[0,1]$, but can even be embedded into the *rationals* between $0$ and $1$. On the other hand, $\omega_1$ itself is not order-isomorphic to any subset of $\mathbb R$.

On yet another hand, that may not matter (at least if we restrict our attention to finite input tapes -- which, however, is a pretty big if), because there are only countably many different Turing machines, so since $\omega_1$ is a regular cardinal, there will be *some* countable ordinal before which every terminating computation has terminated. And *that* upper bound *can* be embedded into $\mathbb Q\cap[0,1]$.

---

As a philosophical comment to your question, the real line is merely a (fairly good) *mathematical model* of physical time. It may or may not correspond to actual physical time, and there seems to be no particular reason to insist that the hypothetical, non-physical, "philosophical time" that the "supertask" concept evokes ought to be constrained to things that can be modeled by the real line. Why not the [long line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_%28topology%29), for example?

Comment: In terms of your last point, there has been some (speculative and controversial) talk of time being quantized, meaning there could be a smallest unit of time, which would mean time is not a continuum like the real line. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_time

Comment: @ToddWilcox: That's one reason why I downgraded "very good" (as my first draft read) to "fairly good"... :-)

Comment: I didnt interpret the possibility of computing beyond $\omega_1$ as trivial, the machine can in principle reach that stage in finite time, only the behaviour is not interesting. And if you keep running, wouldnt the machine reach $\omega_2$, and beyond? my be I am wrong in assuming that he is assuming that $\omega_2$ can be reached in finite time too.

Comment: @julianfernandez: He's not assuming _anything_ about "can be reached in finite time". He's saying "let's consider this strange inductive definition of a function from ordinals to machine states, and study its mathematical properties". There's no need to interpret that as a process that takes place in physical time (or for that matter in any particular non-physical time) -- such an interpretation can _at most_ be a source of intuition about the project. The actual math doesn't need it and is not constrained by it.

Comment: I know, I am talking about classical interpretation of time, sure, time could be discrete, and even not well ordered (something similar to a foam) at small Planck scales

Comment: @ Henning I am pretty sure you are wrong about not reaching stage $\omega_1$ in finite time. Let me find the quote so I can paste it.

Comment: "The essence of an infinitely fast computer, of course, is that it is able to
complete infinitely many steps of computation in a finite amount of time"
An infinitely fast computation, therefore, when measured by the number of computational steps in it, can be viewed (perhaps paradoxically) as being
infinitely long."  
"a lightening fast computation that actually completes all
the steps in an infinite algorithm; the computational time is infinite when
measured by the number of computational steps"

Comment: @julianfernandez: That's intuitive motivation, not part of the mathematical development. The actual mathematics _doesn't_ depend on any real-valued time axis; the sentence you're quoting from the introduction is merely a vivid, non-technical, handwavy attempt to suggest a reason to _care_ about the precise mathematics that follows.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, the real line can be of size $\aleph_2$, but also of size $\aleph_{5223435}$ and even $\aleph_{\omega_1}$. All these are consistent with ZFC, and unless you assume something additional you can't really prove a lot about the cardinality of the continuum.

Secondly, you are correct. Assuming the axiom of choice a set cannot be partitioned into a strictly larger number of parts. That means that if $\Bbb R$ has cardinality $\aleph_2$, then every partition must have size of *at most* $\aleph_2$. However, do note that there are $\aleph_3$ many ordinals of cardinality $\aleph_2$.

Comment: Thanks Ross, this tablet has some keyboard issues...

Comment: Thanks to both answers, give me some time to digest the answers,and I'll be back, perhaps asking some clarification.I am not sure to understand them yet.

Comment: So, do this mean that Hamkins transfinite time is implicitly assuming (choice + ¬CH), because his time line  would imply that the reals have a cardinality larger than $\aleph_1$ (actually any arbitrary high cardinality).

Comment: @julian: I don't know what he assumed... Do you have a particular reference?

Comment: Sure, you can find the article here: http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9808093, but I am pretty sure he doesn't mention any assumptions explicitly, beyond what I already mentioned: that a finite amount of time can be divided into a number of steps of arbitrarily high cardinality

Comment: @julian: That's almost sixty pages. Can you pinpoint me better?

Comment: All he says about it is in point 1.How the Machines Work. But regardless of what he doesn't say explicitly, your argument above seem to be that he has to assume ¬CH, otherwise he could not put there more than $\aleph_1$ intervals (very small but finite time step intervals). What other alternative could be possible is you assume CH instead?

Comment: @julianfernandez *Nowhere* in the paper do they assume anything like $\lnot\mathsf{CH}$ and certainly not that the continuum is $\aleph_2$. There is one proof, not in the section you suggest, where they prove a result via an absoluteness argument that involves forcing (But this is not what you had in mind anyway).

Comment: @Andres I never said that the paper assumes that explicitly, I only asked if he must perhaps be assuming it implicitly (without mention it), to make sense of Asaf's answer (you should pay more attention before bullyng me)

Comment: @julian: My answer only points out that in the presence of choice if $P$ is a partition of $A$, then $|P|\leq|A|$. The exact cardinal of the continuum is undecidable in ZFC, and it seems that what Andres and Henning wrote is correct. The paper is not interested in the cardinal of the continuum. Only in the fact that computation ends in a countable time.

Comment: @julianfernandez No one is bullying you.

Comment: ok, but the CH states that the cardinality of the reals is $\aleph_1$, and as if you stated that the model has the same number of partitions than of points, and the number of partition can be higher than $\aleph_1$, what other possibility is left that you are using a model with $\not CH$? I never said that Henkins was interested in that issue, I only asked if his model of time implied a time with a number of arbitrarily high time intervals. That, it seems that I got it wrong if Makholm answer is correct.

Comment: @julian: Yes. If you assume that $\Bbb R$ can be partitioned into strictly more than $\aleph_1$ parts then $\sf CH$ fails. But you need to remember that there are $\aleph_2$ ordinals of size $\aleph_1$, and therefore one can still take pretty large ordinals, even if one is limited by cardinality. As a side note, Andres is probably the nicest guy I have met on this site.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo sorry, I misinterpreted you, I got dizzy because a lot o people were saying that I stated things that I didn't, so they didn't read carefully and just put "incorrect" answers too fast (incorrect in the sense that misinterpret what I wrote too easily)

Comment: @Asaf: My understanding is that Julian was ultimately asking about _order-preserving_ embeddings of ordinals into $\mathbb R$. That limits us more than cardinality does: No matter where on the aleph scale $\mathbb R$ itself falls, it can embed only the countable-or-finite ordinals, of which there are only $\aleph_1$.

Comment: @Henning: Yes. Order preservation indeed poses a more severe limitation. But that wasn't what the question said. It said partition.

Answer (score 5):

$2^{\aleph_0}$ can be almost anything, it is not limited to $\aleph_2$.  As long as you can't divide the line into more than $2^{\aleph_0}$ segments, the fact that $|2^{\aleph_0} \times 2^{\aleph_0}|=|2^{\aleph_0}|$ means you have no trouble with more points than intervals.  Whatever $2^{\aleph_0}$ is, $\mathbb R^n$ has that number of points in it, too.

Comment: You can't if you assume the axiom of choice. :-) Without the axiom of choice it might be the case that you can divide the continuum into way more parts than elements! And people complain about the Banach-Tarski paradox... :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila:  I think the question was in the spirit of ZFC.  But I would love to see a reference for that (it must be disjoint parts?!)  Sometimes we educate more than OP.

Comment: Take any model in which $\aleph_1\nleq2^{\aleph_0}$ (Solovay's model, Shelah's model, Truss' model[s], Feferman-Levy model, any model of ZF+AD); there is a definable map from $\Bbb R$ onto $\omega_1$. Then you can map $\Bbb R$ onto $\Bbb R\cup\omega_1$ which has a strictly larger cardinality.

Comment: Ross, you may enjoy this answer, and the link there: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/243549/462