# What is known about the quotient group $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request

Let $G = \mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Q}$. Is this an interesting group to study?

Is it isomorphic to any more natural mathematical objects?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Its structure is completely determined, being it a divisible torsion free abelian group; it's torsion free because, for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $n>0$, and $x\in\mathbb{R}$,

$$
n(x + \mathbb{Q}) = \mathbb{Q}
$$

is equivalent to $nx\in\mathbb{Q}$, so to $x\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Thus $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ is a vector space of dimension $\mathfrak{c}=\lvert\mathbb{R}\rvert$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, by a cardinality argument. This implies, as observed in comments, that, as $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces and so as abelian groups,

$$
\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}\cong\mathbb{R}.
$$

Finding a basis for it would imply finding a Hamel basis of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, because of the canonical $\mathbb{Q}$-linear mapping

$$
\pi\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}
$$

Just choose elements $x_\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ that are mapped to a basis of $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$; adding $1$ to this family would produce a Hamel basis for $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Doesn't that imply that $\mathbb R/\mathbb Q\cong \mathbb R$? Basically, they are both vector spaces over $\mathbb Q$ with bases of the same cardinality.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, of course. But you can't *name* such an isomorphism without naming a Hamel basis.

Comment: Sure, my point isn't that there is any constructable isomorphism, but to let the OP realize that the purely "abelian group" structure of $\mathbb R$ is not what he thinks it is. The fact that $\mathbb R/\mathbb Q\equiv \mathbb R$ is the most bold-faced way of making that strangeness apparent.

Comment: "But you can't name such an isomorphism without naming a Hamel basis. " Why is that so? Of course the existence of a Hamel basis implies the existence of an isomorphism. But why the converse? I'm not really convinced.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I'm not convinced too. ;-)

Comment: I thought it was possible that $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q} > \mathbb{R}$ if you didn't have the axiom of choice, and specifically if every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is measurable.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it is an abelian torsion-free with an uncountable ammount (cardinal) of elements and, thus,  it is also a non finitely-generated group.

You may also be interested in the fact that

$$\Bbb R/\Bbb Q\cong\left(\Bbb R/\Bbb Z\right)/\left(\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z\right)$$

so that $\,\Bbb R/\Bbb Q\,$ is a quotient of the [circle group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_group)

Comment: It is also a [non countably-generated group](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346244/does-a-countable-set-generate-a-countable-group)!

Comment: Indeed so, @user1729 . Thanks.