# Is $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ an interesting group?

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, soft-question

Inspired by the construction of the non-mesurable Vitali set I thought about the group $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ (the additive group of the real numbers modulo the rationals). There must be some literature for this, but I haven't found any and it is hard to google. Does anyone know where to find results about this group?

Comment: Cf: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/355852/what-is-known-about-the-quotient-group-mathbbr-mathbbq