# Cardinality of "$x-y\in\Bbb Q$"-equivalence class of $1/\sqrt2$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

> For $x,y\in I:=[0,1]$ define the relation on $I$ as $x-y\in \Bbb Q$.
>
> How big (using cardinal number) is the cardinality of the equivalence class $[1/\sqrt2]$?

I have tried to solve it by finding the equivalence class but I'm not sure about the method that I can solve the question.

Please, can you help me to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Every member of that equivalence class will be of the form $\frac1{2^{1/2}}+q$ for some rational $q$. (Why?) How many numbers of such form are there? This gives you an upper bound on the cardinality of the equivalence class (that is, there are *at most* that many elements in the equivalence class). You should be able to show that there are *at least* that many elements in the equivalence class, as well, by giving an explicit set of that many numbers of the appropriate form.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways of interpreting your question. One is, given $x\in I$, how large is $[x]$. This set is countably infinite, that is, of cardinality $\aleph_0=|\mathbb N|$. This is simply because $\mathbb Q$ is countable, so if $x-y\in\mathbb Q$, then $y$ can only be one of countably many numbers. And also, $\mathbb Q$ is dense, so there are rationals arbitrarily close to $0$ (both positive and negative), which means that there are reals within rational distance of $x$, both from above and from below, and as close to $x$ as desired. This shows that $[x]$ is infinite, but we already showed it is countable. In particular, $|[2^{-1/2}]|=\aleph_0$.

The other interpretation is what is the size of the collection of all equivalence classes. This is a trickier question. The collection has the same size as the reals, $\mathfrak c=|\mathbb R|$, but any proof of this fact uses some non-trivial fragment of the axiom of choice. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/243544/462), and the slides I link to in the answer there.