# Existence of surjection implies existence of injection?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. If there exists a surjection $f : A \to B$ then there exists an injection $g : B \to A$.

Proof: given $b \in B$ select an element $a \in f^{-1}(b)$. Denote this element by $g(b)$. Then $g(b) \in f^{-1}(b)$ so that $f(g(b)) = b$. Consequently $g(b_1) = g(b_2)$ implies $f(g(b_1)) = f(g(b_2))$ so that $b_1 = b_2$. We conclude $g$ is an injection. QED

Is the axiom of choice *required* to make this argument rigorous?

Comment: See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176972/is-there-a-cantor-schroder-bernstein-statement-about-surjective-maps).

Comment: Without choice, we can have surjections without injections. We can in fact have an equivalence relation on $\mathbb R$ such that there are more equivalence classes than reals.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo that last statement is surprising. Do you have a link or a citation?

Comment: Yes. See for example [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/243544/462).

Comment: Just to be explicit: As shown in the links, it is an open problem whether your statement is equivalent to the (full) axiom of choice. It certainly needs at least some amount of choice to be proved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a proof that the existence of *any* injection depends on the axiom of choice, but the existence of a right inverse is equivalent to AC, as follows.  Let $X$ be a set not containing $\emptyset$ and consider the set $Y = \{(z, A)\ |\ z\in A \in X\}$.  Define $f:Y\rightarrow X$ by $f((z,A)) = A$.  If $g$ is a right inverse of $f$, then $g^*(A)$ given by the the first element of the ordered pair $g(A)$ is a choice function.

Answer (score 0):

It is. In fact, I believe it can be show that the universal truth of this theorem is equivalent to the axiom of choice.

Comment: In fact, this is equivalent to the axiom of choice.

Comment: It's clear that AC is equivalent to the statement "every surjection splits". But if the injection $g$ in the question doesn't split $f$, how do you construct the choice function?

Comment: This is a nontrivial affair. See this: http://www.math.uwo.ca/~srankin/courses/4123/2011/zorns_lemma.pdf

Comment: Now I'm *really* confused... what does this have to do with Zorn's Lemma?

Comment: Zorn's lemma is another equivalent of the axiom of choice.  This construction is nontrivial.

Comment: http://planetmath.org/surjectionandaxiomofchoice

Comment: @ncmathsadist I'm well aware that Zorn's Lemma is equivalent to the axiom of choice, but I don't see how that's relevant to this discussion. Your link to planetmath just reiterates the fact that "every surjection splits" is equivalent to the axiom of choice, which I commented on above, and which is the content of the accepted answer. In Asaf's answer here http://math.stackexchange.com/a/192486/7062, he says that it's still open whether "surjection $X\rightarrow Y$ implies injection $Y\rightarrow X$" implies the axiom of choice, which is what you claim.

Comment: I didn't say this was a trivial implication.

Comment: I would love to see your proof!

Comment: I don't understand, are you saying that you have a proof that the partition principle implies the axiom if choice?? All the linked proofs do not contain such proof.

Comment: By the way, the problem whether or not the partition principle implies the axiom of choice is the oldest open problem of set theory. I am not aware of any progress made towards it in the last twenty years. So if you have a proof, I would love to see that.